# Can a non-unitary free operation on a resource state be reversed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator, reversibility

Under the framework of resource theories like entanglement, asymmetry, athermaility, etc, a set of operations $\mathcal{O} \subset \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is chosen (e.g., LOCC) due to physical limitations, which corresponds to a set of free states $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})$ (e.g., separable states) where any $\Phi \in \mathcal{O}$ maps any free state $\rho \in \mathcal{F}$ to a free state, i.e., $\Phi(\rho) \in \mathcal{F}$. As such $\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}) \backslash \mathcal{F}$ is the set of resource states, they can be used to perform tasks we otherwise cannot under such limitations, hence the notion of resource.

Also, it should be noted that $I \in \mathcal{O}$ (not doing anything is free), and any $\Phi, \Lambda \in \mathcal{O}$ should satisfy $\Lambda \circ \Phi \in \mathcal{O}$ (closed under composition). It could also be that the free states are chosen because they are special (e.g., coherence as resource) and $\mathcal{O}$ is picked later in correspondence. Which comes first is not important, as long the requirements are met.

A key topic in such theories is state conversion, as in which state can be converted to which under $\mathcal{O}$, so we can know what can be done given some resource. A resource measure $M$ can be concocted (e.g., von Neumann entropy, robustness, entanglement of formation, etc) in part to reflect this ($M(\rho) > M(\sigma)$ can mean $\rho$ is better than $\sigma$ in some respect) but for $\rho$ to make $\sigma$, i.e.,$\exists \Phi \in \mathcal{O}, \Phi(\rho) = \sigma$, is what makes $\rho$ definitive better, since all that $\sigma$ can do, $\rho$ can by making it. Such a conversion usually performs a task that whittles down the resource state making it not (as) productive (e.g., teleportation).

The interest here is the reversibility of state conversion.

Among the free operations there exists a set of free unitary operation $\mathcal{U} \subset \mathcal{O}$ (e.g., local unitaries), where $U(\rho) = \sigma$ can be reversed by $U^{-1}(\sigma) = \rho$, thus they belong to the same unitary equivalence class, they can be seen as having the same capabilities. $\mathcal{U}$ does not whittle down a resource state, but can be used to express $\Phi$ by the form $\Phi(\rho) = \mathrm{Tr}_E U ( \rho \otimes | 0\rangle\langle 0|_E ) U^\dagger$.

However, for a non-unitary free operation $\Phi \in \mathcal{O} \backslash \mathcal{U}$, we know that its inverse $\Phi^{-1} \notin \mathcal{O}$, because it can map some free state to a resource state, i.e., $\Phi(\rho \notin \mathcal{F}) = \sigma \in \mathcal{F}$, $\Phi^{-1}(\sigma) = \rho$, meaning it would create resource from none which is not allowed. But, what if, there exists some other non-unitary free operation $\Lambda \in \mathcal{O} \backslash \mathcal{U}$ not the inverse to $\Phi$, i.e., $\Lambda \Phi \neq I$, only circumstancially reverses a state conversion between a pair of resource states $\Phi(\rho \notin \mathcal{F}) = \sigma \notin \mathcal{F}, \Lambda(\sigma) = \rho$?

A simple example would be for $\mathcal{O}$ to be unital ($\Phi(\rho) 
 = \sum_i p_i U_i \rho U_i^\dagger$), and $\mathcal{F}$ to solely be the maximally mixed state $\frac{1}{d}I$ (where $\Phi(\frac{1}{d}I) = \frac{1}{d}I$), any other state would be a resource. Then as given above, $\sigma$ should be more mixed than $\rho$, if it is reversible it would be somewhat strange, as their unitary orbits would be joined into a single larger equivalence class, circumstantially by the pair $\Phi$ and $\Lambda$, yet they are supposed to usually whittle down a resource, in this case, make $\rho$ more mixed, towards $\frac{1}{d}I$. (update: Actually in this example there is no nonunitary reversibility, as the complete transformation criterion is given by majorization, if the eigenvalues of $\rho$ change there is no going back. But what about other resources?)

The replacement map $\mathrm{Tr}(\sigma)\rho$ is resource generating, unless $\rho \in \mathcal{F}$ (in which case $\sigma$ is discarded and replaced with an abundantly existing free state) but that is not the premise.
It is known under the asymptotic limit (many copies of a state), $\Phi(\rho^{\otimes n}) = \sigma^{\otimes m}$ can be reversed $\Lambda(\sigma^{\otimes m}) = \rho^{\otimes n}$ with marginal lose in fidelity. That is not of concern here.

By definition any $\Phi \in \mathcal{O}$, $\Phi(\rho) = \sigma$ for any $\rho, \sigma \in \mathcal{F}$. Does this sufficiently imply for any non-unitary operation to 'map states in one direction'? In the literature, there seems to be no broad discussion regarding the restrictions on how resource states convert to one another (non-asymptotically), maybe it is of no import, or this is not a valid question. But if there is talk that specifically addresses this matter please refer it here.

Comment: the edit changes the context significantly. What resource theory are you considering then? You want only maps that do not create entanglement from separable states? Or something else? Regarding the last statement, I don't know if it helps but if I remember correctly you can have $\Lambda\Phi=I$ only if the maps are unitary channels. This is showed in Watrous' book

Comment: @glS, I am considering resource theories in general. For entanglement, the largest set of free operations would be the non-entangling maps. $\Lambda \Phi = I$ would mean any $\rho$ is reversed, that would lead to a unitary, but I specifically want to know if there is only some $\rho$ that is reversed where $\Lambda \Phi \neq I$, they are supposed to be non-unitary free operations that usually whittle down resources, but what if there exists such a pair where one reverses the other?

Comment: So you are fixing a specific subset $\mathcal S$ of maps, which depends on which resource theory you consider, and a state $\rho$ and a map $\Phi$, and ask if there is $\Lambda\in\mathcal S$ such that $\Lambda(\Phi(\rho))=\rho$? Won't the answer depend on what is $\mathcal S$ (e.g. the answer is trivial if there are no restrictions on $\mathcal S$)? How do you answer this in the general case? Also, the title doesn't really reflect what is being asked

Comment: @glS, I guess there are problems with how I phrased the question. The restriction for the allowed operations is for any quantum resource in general where the free states are mapped to free states, and cannot be free unitary. I feel such operations should not reverse each other circumstantially for any resource state, but cannot find an article that discusses reversibility that is non-asymptotic and non-unitary.

Comment: The question is rather unclear. Do you think you could rewrite it from scratch making it clear what the question is, and separating the "context" part clearly and visibly?

Comment: Other than that, of course you can have a map which can only be reversed on certain inputs.

Answer (score 1):

The replacement channel is a trivial example.

For input state $\sigma$, the channel gives you output $\Lambda(\sigma) = \text{Tr}(\sigma)\rho$.